Why the AWS Cognito token is different when registering for the first time using the ellaisys/aws-cognito library in Laravel?
I am utilizing the following library:
https://github.com/ellaisys/aws-cognito

The token received upon initial registration and that is different. Following a password reset, the returned token in the IdToken is a JWT (JSON Web Token). Is it possible to use the initial token as a JWT?
I am unable to decode the token that was initially generated.
